# Troubleshoot Oracle Stored Procedure when it only returns -1

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, odp.net

I have a stored procedure which works when I test it manually and directly in the database.
The procedure doesn't return anything. And since it works fine when I test it manually, I am not showing it here.

But when I am calling it from the code, I am getting the return value -1, which I understand as "something went wrong".

```
command.CommandText = Properties.Settings.Default.OracleProcedureNewCable;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.BindByName = true;

command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_tag_id", Value = (object)cable.TagId ?? DBNull.Value });

return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery returned -1

Setting a breakpoint didn't give me much information about why it went wrong.
How do I troubleshoot in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean anything went wrong, `ExecuteNonQuery` returns -1 when there were no rows affected or if there was a rollback.

Comment: Even the title of your question contains false premise that SP returns ANY value. It does not. You also have a couple of false premises in the body. Please read my comment to the answer here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62836847/1704458. This is the one of the reasons why I did not upvote your question. If you would simply ask "why" `ExecuteNonQuery` on SP returns (-1)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I am calling it from the code, I am getting the return value -1, which I understand as "something went wrong".

That is incorrect.

"For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1."

[DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery?view=netcore-3.1)

When something goes wrong it will throw an Exception.

And Oracle stored procedures don’t even have a return value.  They can have output parameters, including result sets with output sysrefcursor parameters, but they don’t have a return value.

Comment: I am not going to post another answer. I will ask you to improve yours. The OP has made a principal mistake - this is not a stored procedure return. This is a return from `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`. SP does not return ANY value. And for the statements that don't return number of records solution is to return (-1). Because, for example, `Update` can return (0) updated records.

Comment: What improvement do you suggest?  OP thinks -1 return indicates a failure.  I posted the doc quote that corrects that.

Comment: You should explain what I commented. The question sounds like SP has a return *"Troubleshoot Oracle Stored Procedure when it only returns -1"*